# Stay at same working directory when changing to sudo

Tags: shell, directory, sudo

When working on the command line, I often change to sudo using `sudo -i`. However, my working directory changes automatically to `/root`. I never want to go there; I want to stay where I was! How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to run a shell as `root` instead running individual commands with `sudo some_command ...`. (Using a `root` shell is more dangerous.)

Comment: @Bodo I can't speak for op, but the usecase that brings me here is there's a folder I don't have permissions to even enter unless I'm root.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use `sudo -s` instead, it would not change your current directory to `/root`, though some of your environment variables would not be those of root.

This [page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6188826&postcount=4) from the Ubuntu Forums has a nice summary:

```
Summary of the differences found   
                                               corrupted by user's 
                HOME=/root      uses root's PATH     env vars
sudo -i         Y               Y[2]                 N
sudo -s         N               Y[2]                 Y
sudo bash       N               Y[2]                 Y
sudo su         Y               N[1]                 Y
```

This page from from Ubuntu's documentation has much more [background information on sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a bunch, simple but great little overview!

Comment: @user1162541 Happy to be able to help.

Comment: `sudo -iu` works for me http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515069&p=9493695#post9493695

Comment: During my test, env vars of `sudo -i` is still corrupted by user's env vars. The only way to avoid to this is to use `su -l`.

Comment: as of 2023-01 `sudo -s` also sets $HOME to '/root' (at least on debian >=7.4 or manjaro21

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use `su`, there is a way to stay in the same directory.

```
su - user -c "cd `pwd`; bash"
```

What’s going on here:

- `su - user` = login as *`user`*
- `-c` which means "run a command in the new user’s shell"
- `` -c "cd `pwd`" `` the command we give is to switch to the current directory (`` `pwd` ``) – but because we use the backticks in double quotes, the `pwd` command is evaluated before we run the `su` command, so that we actually switch to the directory we’re in NOW as the old user.

  - By contrast, `` -c 'cd `pwd`' `` would execute the `pwd` command in the new shell, so this would evaluate to `cd /root`, which, of course, won’t accomplish anything.

  The only problem here is that the new shell exits right after running the command, so then we add:
- `` -c "cd `pwd`; bash" `` which means "run `bash` (new shell) after running the `cd` command. The bash shell doesn’t exit until we log out of it.

Note that you can replace `` `pwd` `` with `$(pwd)`.  They’re functionally the same,
but the abundance of quote-like characters can become hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and I'm not allowed to run anything other than `sudo su - devuser` on dev server, so this is what I came up with:

1. In devuser's .profile switch back to previous user home if found:

```bsh
prev_user_home=$(~/bin/home.sh)
if [ -n $prev_user_home ] ; then
        cd $prev_user_home
fi
```

2. A script to determine a previous user. The script is placed in devuser's bin  directory:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#brings you back home after sudo su

function get_owner {
  pid=$1
  echo $(ps ouid -p $pid h | tr -d ' ')
}

pid=$$
my_uid=$(get_owner $pid)
uid=$my_uid
i=0
while [[ $uid == $my_uid && $i -lt 20 ]] ; do
    pid=$(ps -o ppid= $pid)
    uid=$(get_owner $pid)
    i=$((i+1))
done

user_home=$(getent passwd $uid | cut -d ':' -f '6')
if [[ -d $user_home && $uid != 0 ]] ; then
    echo $user_home
fi
```

It goes up a process tree and checks if process owning user changed.

Answer (score 0):

K.I.S.S = Keep It Simple Student

The easiest way without complication (if you are executing a predefined script) is just to temporarily set the HOME environment variable after sudo -i.  But don't forget to change it back when done.  There's probably a way in Linux to call a script when you exit sudo, but I'm not sure what that is.  You will need to chown whatever files the myuser needs to access when done since everything will be owned by root.

```
sudo -i
export HOME=/home/myuser
```

> ... do stuff

```
export HOME=/root
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If both users have access to the working dir:

```
sudo su -- $USER
```

Note that if you become a user that doesn't have access to the working dir,  the new user won't be able to do any read/write operations in it.

Or to just be root in working dir:

```
sudo su --
```